# gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr

Tags: debian, apt, gpg

While trying to receive keys in my Debian Stretch server, I get this error:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.4B7hWtn7Rm/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.4B7hWtn7Rm/S.dirmngr' failed: No such file or directory
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

Comment: See https://k6.io/docs/get-started/installation/troubleshooting/#error-importing-k6s-gpg-key; you can run `sudo gpg -k` and then try again

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Installing the package `dirmngr` fixed the error.

```
user@debian-server:~$ sudo apt-get install dirmngr
```

Retrying :

```
user@debian-server:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.haKuPppywi/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
gpg: key A6A19B38D3D831EF: public key "Xamarin Public Jenkins (auto-signing) <releng@xamarin.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

Comment: Had same problem on Debian 9.4. Installing dirmngr fixed it.

Comment: I got the same error of the OP, but I already have latest gpg installed.

Comment: installing `gpg` fixed it for me on a Debian 9.3.  `dirmngr` was already installed.

Comment: Same issue on Raspbian 9.8 stretch. Installing dirmngr resolved it. Thanks.

Comment: I found that it was because I'd never used gpg before. `sudo apt-install gpg` if it isn't installed already - then run `sudo gpg -k` to create the dirmgr directory and try again.

Answer (score 11):

I wasn't able to get dirmngr to work, but you can also just import the key directly using apt-key add. The GPG public key is often listed at the root of the repo like http://origin-download.mono-project.com/repo/

```
curl https://origin-download.mono-project.com/repo/xamarin.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: You need to run dirmngr if it's not already running.

Comment: `dirmngr` was running, but still no joy...  If the keyserver happens to be [keyserver.ubuntu.com](http://keyserver.ubuntu.com) then you can access via a browser and search for the public key using the `--recv-keys` parameter, then simply use `apt-key add` as per this answer

Comment: Following this answer, I managed to download a `.asc` file from keyserver.ubuntu.com, then to import it with `sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/apt/keyrings/<YOUR-APP>.gpg --import armored-keys.asc`

Answer (score 0):

As said, the dirmngr package should be installed, but it may happen that apt does not work and cannot install any package.
Don't worry. Search dirmngr package on https://packages.debian.org selecting your distribution version, download it on the linux machine and install it using dpkg command, for example:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gnupg2/dirmngr_2.1.18-8~deb9u4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i dirmngr_2.1.18-8~deb9u4_amd64.deb
```

Then you'll be able to run apt-key command to fetch the missing keys.